# Icons not showing in Opera browser

Tags: html, css, icons

So I recently finished making a site for my friend who needed one. And it's just a simple HTML and CSS site, no JS or PHP, just a simple representation sort of site. And so my other friend went to the site on his browser which is opera GX and the icons wouldn't load. Everything else was working fine, except the icons. They were still there, but as if it had `display: none;` assigned for all the `i` elements. So I downloaded the opera GX browser and went on the site, and all the icons loaded fine for me.

I haven't tried anything as I think its a problem on his side and not with the browser. If it loaded fine for me then I'm thinking its a problem that only he can fix.

here is the CSS used on the icons:

```css
.features i {
    margin: 50px 0 25px 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #1e90ff;
}
```

I would like for someone to give me an explanation as to what is happening here and if its a browser issue or an issue on my friend's side.

Comment: What does `i` refer to?

Comment: Icon. And I've fixed the problem now so it doesn't matter any more.